# Postgres: Finding search_path for given user and modifying it permanently

Tags: postgresql

I want to find the search_path for the current user and modify it permanently.

I can find it using `show search_path` but when I try to find out using the below query, then it returns nothing

```
SELECT r.rolname, d.datname, rs.setconfig
FROM   pg_db_role_setting rs
LEFT   JOIN pg_roles      r ON r.oid = rs.setrole
LEFT   JOIN pg_database   d ON d.oid = rs.setdatabase
WHERE  r.rolname = 'vishal'
```

My questions are:

1. Why these 2 returns the different result. I think `show search_path` returns the default value as `"$user", public` if nothing is found.
2. Is it ok to set the current user's search_path permanently by finding it using `show search_path` and appending myschema to it by using below command?

```
ALTER ROLE vishal in DATABASE mydb set search_path = "$user", public, myschema;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to find out whence the setting came, try `pg_settings`:

```
SELECT setting, source, boot_val, reset_val, sourcefile, sourceline
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name = 'search_path';
```

Then you can see the source of the current setting.

That should help you to find out why two sessions have different `search_path` set.

You can set your `search_path` using `ALTER ROLE ... IN DATABASE` as you suggest, but be aware that

1. The setting won't take effect until you disconnect and reconnect.
2. The setting will be overwritten by any `SET` command in the session.

Comment: this clears my first question.
is it safe to assume that `show search_path` will always give me the current user search_path latest value?

Comment: I tried to answer the second part too in my extended answer.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
postgres=# SELECT rolname, rolconfig FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname=<name> ;
```

does the job a little more straight forward.